# Can't get Contact ID from EMAILBOX Object

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2007

I'm trying to get Contact ID from Email box using ResolveName method but it doesn't returns me the Contact ID Related with that contact. [image: my code]

MS reference https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.emailaddress_properties(v=exchg.80).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Id only gets returned if the Contact is located in the users Contacts folder. For Global Address List objects that are returned the Id will always be null because you can't do any further operations on these objects (eg you can do a GetItem on GAL Contacts). The only other valid operation you could do on a GAL contact would be to Load to UserPhoto on 2013 and for this you would just pass the Email Addresss of the contact.

Cheers
Glen

Comment: HI thanks for your answer. Which WellKnownFolderName should I set to get My own User Photo?

Comment: On Exchange 2013 the best way to do that is to use the GetUserPhoto operation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj190905%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx